# getting 503 error while updating db after inserting on same table on Google AppEngine in android

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am getting 503 error while updating my table on Google AppEngine db using endpoints. I am calling Update function immediate after inserting in same table. In other table only update is working good in other screens for other tables.

The error is

```
503 Service Unavailable

{

    "code" : 503, 

    "errors" : [ {

         "domain" : "global",

         "message" : "javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Object does not exist",

         "reason" : "backendError"

    } ], 

    "message" : "javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Object does not exist"
}
```

And my code is.

```
Ordermasterendpoint endpointOrderMaster = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(endpointBuilderOrderMaster).build();


try {
    CollectionResponseOrderMaster OrderMasterCollection = endpointOrderMaster.listOrderMaster().execute();


    for(OrderMaster OrderMasterCollections : OrderMasterCollection.getItems()) {


        try
        {
            if(OrderMasterCollections.getOrderMasterID().toString().equals(OrderID))
            {

                OrderMasterCollections.set("status", "Canclled");

                OrderMaster OrderResult = endpointOrderMaster.updateOrderMaster(OrderMasterCollections).execute();

                break;
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print("\n\nException in Endpoint is :::::::::::::"+e.getMessage());
        }

    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Actual error is in

```
public OrderMaster updateOrderMaster(OrderMaster ordermaster) {
        EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
        try {
            if (!containsOrderMaster(ordermaster)) {
                throw new EntityNotFoundException("Object does not exist");
            }
            mgr.persist(ordermaster);
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return ordermaster;
    }
```

I have not mention insert code in above. It is working fine. But immediate after I am trying to update my same table with above code.

Please help me I am stuck I don't know how it is not working while update with other table is working fine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer.

I dont know how but problem was in ID field. 
My unique ID field of table `OrderMaster` was `OrderMasterID` so error was there the field name should be in small letter leke `ordermasterID`.

I changed `OrderMasterID` to `ordermasterID` and it works. It get `ID in contains` method. In case of `OrderMasterID` I got `null` value in `contains` method.